# how to return object as key in groupby function using underscore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

my `json` looks like

[image]

I am trying to group by NodeGroup using underscore library

```
vm.populatedNodeGroups = _($scope.nodes).groupBy(function (o) { 
                return o.NodeGroup.Name;
            });
```

In an `vm.populatedNodeGroups` I get two keys (Are One Routers , Are Two Switches) with two arrays each.

What I am trying to get is two Node Group Objects with Two arrays each.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rHcs45cObVw3tu3HMDnz?p=preview)

I would say, that you are almost there. this could be our view, consuming the underscore groupBy:

```
<div ng-controller="TheCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="(key, values) in populatedNodeGroups">
    <h3>{{key}}</h3>
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="value in values">{{value | json}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is our controller, doing the **`groupBy`**

```
app.controller('TheCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {       

      var result = _(data)
      .groupBy(function (o) { 
        return o.NodeGroup.Name;
      })
      ;

    $scope.populatedNodeGroups = result;

}])
```

The result would be like

**Area Two Switches**

- `{ "NodeGroup": { "Name": "Area Two Switches" ... } ... }`
- `{ "NodeGroup": { "Name": "Area Two Switches" ... } ... }`

**Areaa One Routers**

- `{ "NodeGroup": { "Name": "Areaa One Routers" ... } ... }`
- `{ "NodeGroup": { "Name": "Areaa One Routers" ... } ... }`

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rHcs45cObVw3tu3HMDnz?p=preview)

Comment: That's great to see ;) Enjoy angular and underscore ;)